# In elasticsearch 2 docs with same ID

Tags: node.js, elasticsearch, aws-elasticsearch

Hi I'm new to Elasticsearch and I'm using Elasticsearch version 5.6 as I know _id of every doc in Elasticsearch is unique.
but while re-indexing logs I found that. some of doc have same _id. for example below two logs
have same id. How is it possible?

```json
{
  "_index": "orders",
  "_type": "pending",
  "_id": "1473531",
  "_score": 1,
  "_routing": "44540",
  "_parent": "44540",
  "_source": {
    "id": 1473531,
    "level": "info",
    "type": "pending",
    "status": "",
    "message": "Order marked cancelled by system"
  }
}
```

```json
{
  "_index": "orders",
  "_type": "confirmed",
  "_id": "1473531",
  "_score": 1,
  "_source": {
    "id": 1473531,
    "source_address": "Independence, MO 64055",
    "dest_address": "MO 64138",
    "short_source": "Select Physical Therapy",
    "short_dest": "Home",
    "customer_remarks": null,
    "source_lat_long": ["39.0334554", "-94.3761432"],
    "dest_lat_long": ["38.986449", "-94.4661768"]
  }
}
```

Comment: Both documents do not have the same type, one is `pending` and the other is `confirmed`. Just know, though, that types [are going to be removed](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/removal-of-types.html) and you'll have to change your data design.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is because, your type in the index is different.

first document has index `orders` but type as `pending` while other document has same index `orders` but type is `confirmed`.

In latest ES version types are removed, refer [removal of types](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/removal-of-types.html) for more info.